# How to merge DataFrame with Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I want to create a multi-index based on Dates and Times from my `DataFrame - df.` 

This actually works and `indexed` returns the correct Multiindex (continuous dates from 02/10/2017 until 31/03/2018 with continuous times from 08:00:00 - 21:55:00 in 5 Min Intervals).

The problem is that my dataset doesn't have complete observations. Means, for a random day there could be missing observations for 08:05:00 until 08:40:00.    My Multiindex has a length of 20496, while my DataFrame has a length of 20486.

When I want to merge the index with my `DataFrame` all observations are `NAN`. Does someone now how to merge the multi index with my initial `DataFrame - df` ?

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, parse_dates=[0], 
index_col=0, sep=',')
df['Date'] = df.index.date
df['Time'] = df.index.time
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(str)
df = df[df['Time'] != '22:00:00']

list_date = set(df['Date'])
list_time = set(df['Time'])

list_date = sorted(list_date)
list_time = sorted(list_time)

iterables = [list_date, list_time]
indexed = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, 
names=['date', 'time'])
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df, index=indexed)
```

`df` output:

```
                            r2     var_v2x        Date      Time
TIME1                                                            
2017-10-02 08:00:00         NaN  0.00008784  2017-10-02  08:00:00
2017-10-02 08:05:00  0.00000000  0.00008784  2017-10-02  08:05:00
2017-10-02 08:10:00  0.00000008  0.00008784  2017-10-02  08:10:00
```

Comment: Seems like you may want to consider having a single `DatetimeIndex` which allows you to use the the [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method. Or simply use `pd.date_range`. As for the merge, I don't see any code relating to that, so hard to know what's going wrong.

Comment: But my guess is that the merge issue is tangential to your actual problem. Can you please provide some sample data (probably right after the `pd.read_csv` line) and your expected output?

Comment: Hi @ALollz, after pd.read_csv my initial index is a DateTimeIndex. But I have to apply a formula to my data that requires two indices. One with the Date, and one with the Times... The output of `df` is totally fine, I added it to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution (probably not an elegant one).

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, sep=',')
df['Date'] = df.index.date
df['Time'] = df.index.time
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(str)

df = df[df['Time'] != '22:00:00']

list_date = set(df['Date'])
list_time = set(df['Time'])

list_date = sorted(list_date)
list_time = sorted(list_time)

iterables = [list_date, list_time]
indexed = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['date', 'time'])

df_index_date = indexed.get_level_values(0)
df_index_time = indexed.get_level_values(1)

df_joined = pd.DataFrame(df_index_date.astype(str) + ' ' + df_index_time.astype(str))
df_joined = df_joined.reset_index()
df_joined = df_joined.set_index(df_joined[0])
del df_joined['index']
del df_joined[0]

df_final = df_joined.join(df)
df_final = df_final.reset_index(drop=True)
df_final = df_final.set_index(indexed)
```